# receiving data sent by websocket in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

The socket connection is established

Client:

```
socket.onopen = function(){
    socket.send("a");
}
```

Server:

```
socket.setEncoding("utf-8");
socket.on('data',function(buff){
   console.log(buff);
   console.log(buff.toString('utf-8'));
});
```

and it got something like this:

```
Buffer 81 81 19 2d 01 51 78 88 80 30 71 21 90  
��-Qx��0q!�
```

How can I get an `a` in the node server?

Some useful notes (maybe):

Client side socket log:

```
WebSocket {binaryType: "blob", extensions: "", protocol: "", onclose: function, onerror: null…}
```

Comment: Use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) module. It makes using WebSockets much easier and safe for legacy browsers.

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is the masked payload of a WebSocket frame. Lets take a closer look at a frame in binary view (your frame seems not valid to me):

```
0x81 0x85 0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d 0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
```

**Byte 0:**

```
1000 0001
^       ^
|       Text opcode
|
FINAL Flag
```

**Byte 1:**

```
1000 0001
^       ^
|       Payload length of 1 byte
|
Masked Flag
```

**Bytes 2-5:**

```
0x37 0xfa 0x21 0x3d
```

Masking is used in this case to "encrypt" the payload when sending it to the server.

**Byte 6:**

```
0x7f 0x9f 0x4d 0x51 0x58
"H"  "e"  "l"  "l"  "o"
```

This is the masked payload. Each byte represents one character.

Now you need to unmask the payload by doing:

```
var masking = new Buffer([0x37, 0xfa, 0x21, 0x3d]);
var payload = new Buffer([0x7f, 0x9f, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x58]);

for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
    payload[i] = payload[i] ^ masking[i % 4];
}

// tada this should be "Hello"
console.log(payload.toString());
```

The "^" is the bitwise operator for XOR. You somehow transform the byte into another state by XORing it with a specified masking byte. As we have four masking bytes "% 4" ensures that we loop through the single masking bytes.

If you are interested on how to implement WebSockets further I recommend reading the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3) and my [transform stream based implementation](https://github.com/bodokaiser/node-walve). The code should be better to read and to understand as the common socket.io package. Also I do not add anything on top so they are more near to the RFC6455 standard.